# Getting Dynamic Table Data With Selenium Python

Tags: python, selenium, parsing, dynamic-tables

So I am trying to parse this data from a dynamic table with selenium, it keeps getting the old data from page 1, I am trying to get gather pages 2's data, I've tried to search for other answers, but haven't found any, some say I need to add a wait period, and I did, however that didn't work.

```
 from selenium import webdriver

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC


browser = webdriver.Firefox()
browser.get('https://www.nyse.com/listings_directory/stock')

symbol_list=[]

table_data=browser.find_elements_by_xpath("//td");

def append_to_list(data):

    for element in data:

      symbol_list.append(element.text)


append_to_list(table_data)

pages=browser.find_elements_by_xpath('//a[@href="#"]')


for page in pages:

    if(page.get_attribute("rel")== "next"):

        if(page.text=="NEXT ›"):

            page.click()

            browser.implicitly_wait(100)

            for elem in browser.find_elements_by_xpath("//td"): //still fetchs the data from page 1

                print(elem.text)

            #print(symbol_list)
```

Comment: I tried to run your code. The function append_to_list will cause stale element error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I modified your script as below.

You should retrieve element in for loop or it will cause stale element reference exception.

And using WebDriverWait to wait for elements to be visible before find element.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from time import sleep

browser = webdriver.Chrome()
browser.get('https://www.nyse.com/listings_directory/stock')

symbol_list = []


while True:
    try:
        table_data = WebDriverWait(browser, 10).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, "//table//td")))
        for i in range(1, len(table_data)+1):
            td_text = browser.find_element_by_xpath("(//table//td)["+str(i)+"]").text
            print(td_text)
            symbol_list.append(td_text)
        next_page = WebDriverWait(browser, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//a[@href="#" and contains(text(),"Next")]')))
        next_clickable = next_page.find_element_by_xpath("..").get_attribute("class")  # li
        if next_clickable == 'disabled':
            break
        print("Go to next page ...")
        next_page.click()
        sleep(3)
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
        break
```

Comment: I ran the same code and it works but it loops forever because it not failing therefore it does not hit the break.

Comment: @Yun... I came up with a different solution. I just modified the xpath pattern instead of adding more code. But yeah the 'disabled' class was the key.  

**My Solution is below.**

`//ul[@class='pagination']/li[not(@class='disabled')]/a[@href='#' and contains(text(),'Next')]`